# How to define one function for two types in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am writing a Rust application. I'd like to have a method to display the text whether it is a string or number. Furthermore, I came up with the following solution, but it is duplicating the code. Is there a better way to do it in Rust?

Notice: I am not looking for a built-in function to print variables. It's just an example. I am looking for a way to implement the same feature for two types.

```
trait Display {
    fn display(self);
}

impl Display for String {
    fn display(self) -> () {
        println!("You wrote: {}", self);
    }
}

impl Display for i32 {
    fn display(self) -> () {
        println!("You wrote: {}", self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let name: String = String::from("Tom Smykowski");
    name.display();
    
    let age: i32 = 22;
    age.display();
}
```

Comment: no, there is not, that why we have macro and derive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You came close. But there is already a trait for converting things to strings - [`std::fmt::Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) (and the automatically-implemented [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/trait.ToString.html)) - so you don't need to have your own trait:

```rust
fn display<T: std::fmt::Display>(v: T) {
    println!("You wrote: {v}");
}

fn main() {
    let name: String = String::from("Tom Smykowski");
    display(name);
    
    let age: i32 = 22;
    display(age);
}
```

Even if you don't need to display the types but do something else with them, we can take the idea from `Display` - instead of defining the whole functionality, define only the pieces that are different. For example, you can create a trait to convert the numbers to strings (or the opposite), or just have functions for each different piece - for example, printing itself without "You wrote: ".

Comment: How to accomplish the second part of the answer?

Comment: @TomSmykowski [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8052656642f2702e9e73ab31825ba8c2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code in the example looks interesting. Worth adding to the answer I think

Answer (score 1):

> I came up with the following solution, but it is duplicating the code. Is there a better way to do it in Rust?

Add a simple declarative macro on top, that is very common in the stdlib and all. e.g.

```rust
macro_rules! impl_display {
    ($t:ty) => {
        impl Display for $t {
            fn display(self) {
                println!("You wrote {self}");
            }
        }
    }
}
impl_display!(String);
impl_display!(i32);
impl_display!(i64);
impl_display!(f32);
```

Although:

- usually the implementations would be different, though not always e.g. implementing an operation on all numeric types, or all unsigned numbers, that's [one of the most common context you'll see it in the stdlib](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/num/mod.rs.html#248-250): the stdlib has no numeric trait but methods are usually implemented on all numeric types, so there's a handful of macros used for all of them, and when new methods are added they're just added to the relevant macro
- here you're already relying on the existence and implementation of `std::fmt::Display` so you should just use that, your trait is not really useful

Comment: How to handle it if implementation for both types are different?

Comment: Handroll it, there's no redundancy if the implementations are different.

Comment: You mean I should then use traits after all? Got it. Is it possible to handle two different implementations with macro by recognizing the type? Sorry, I am a noob

Comment: Macros have no type information (or logic for declarative macros) they can only work off of the syntax. You could have two macros, or a macro with some sort of variant through a keyword. But they can't have the kind of "smarts" where they dispatch off of type information.